Vite rendering on dev but not on build
I am able to render without errors in frontend, using npm run dev.
When I compile with npm run build and run it, it doesn't render some things from a Fetch.
I Have a Parent Component, who sends these fetch data to a child component which renders it.
I have tested to change the api_url in the .env.production from the real backend IP (let's imagin something like http:8.8.8.8) to http://localhost:3000 and it did work, it started rendering things.
Checking the Network tab, with localhost and with the real IP, with both IPs the data is fetched as expected.

Are you using any environment variable? How do you import them in the code?  Vite has a documentation saying how to do this properly (doc)
